# Extracting TensorBoard computational graph to readable files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

Is there any way to extract the computational graph (nodes are the operations) of a neural network (like ResNet) into a readable file (like .json)? Currently, you can see the image of it using TensorBoard.

```
writer = SummaryWriter()
rn18 = models.resnet18().cuda()
x_rn18 = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224).cuda()
writer.add_graph(rn18, x_rn18)
writer.close()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this of any assistance? https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/tensorboard-json-dump-of-all-scalars/69334/2

Comment: @QWERTYL I am using the writer to add a graph (added my code to the question). The link you provided works when you want to extract the training data.